# No Management Studio seen after SQL Server 2008 Express installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-2008-express

I have recently successfully completed the installation of SQL Server 2008 Express.

After installation when I tried accessing SQL Server Express I found there was no Management Studio installed.

Is there an issue with express, that Management Studio is not installed during installation?

If yes how do we access SQL Server in this case?

I also tried installing Management Studio separately but however when I tried to login through the installed Management Studio the server was not found.

Am I missing something?

Does SQL Server Express not  come with Management Studio?

Please Assist.
Thanks

Comment: If you look at the [SQL Server Express download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), you'll see several "versions" of SQL Server Express. The "bare bones" version is just that - nothing but the actual SQL Server engine. But there's also the "Express with Tools" and the "Express with Advanced Services" versions - both of which **do include** SQL Server Management Studio Express. But you can also download the Mgmt Studio Express separately and install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sql server 2008 express does not have management studio.  There is a Management Studio Express, but, IIRC, it must be downloaded separately.

Comment: Agreed.  "Tejas" installed the ENGINE, not SSMS.  SSMS "Express" is avaiable...just go get it.

Comment: The "Express with Tools" and "Express with Advanced Services" versions of SQL Server Express **DO** include the Management Studio Express !

Comment: Installing "Express with Advanced Services" solved the issue thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593). You'll need it to use a management studio with Express edition.